# Setting user picture programmatically doesn't work

Tags: hooks, users

I have a cron hook to check the data of all users for a couple of reasons. One of them is to see if they have a user picture set. If not, i want to give them a default user picture, based on their gender.

I create this picture in the enable hook of my module, and i have a file id. However, when i try to set this on the user, it doesn't work. I've tried multiple things, like:

```
$picture = file_load(variable_get("default_userpic_$gender"));
$account->picture = $picture->fid;
user_save($account);
```

or

```
$picture = file_load(variable_get("default_userpic_$gender"));
$edit = array('picture' => $picture);
user_save($account, $edit);
```

and several variations along this theme. I've also tried to use a user_presave hook and add the picture to the edit there. However, when i check the user, the picture is still NULL. Does anyone know something that might cause this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$picture` is a valid object with a `fid` member?

Comment: Yes, picture is a complete, working file.

Comment: Try using the 2nd example, but with `$edit = array('picture' => $picture->fid);` `picture` is an integer column, I think it'll get upset if you try to stuff a whole file object into it

Comment: By the way, if i check the &$edit field in user_presave, i do see the picture in the edit. The user itself does not update when i check it in Drupal, however.

Comment: I'm quite certain I've tried that one as well, but I'll check again when I get home for good measure.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either :/ It shows up in the $edit array of the presave, but it isn't saved.